# Selecting based on date range in backbone collections

Tags: javascript, sorting, search, backbone.js

I'm working with collections in backbone and would like to quickly filter based on date range. I'm familiar with collection.comparator, and underscore methods like _.sortBy(), but would like to be able to use a method like collection.where() in conjunction with a filter method to only return models that fall between two values.

My initial thought is that it might be best to maintain a sorted collection and employ a sort algorithm, but would like to leverage backbone as much as possible as to not reinvent the wheel if at all possible. Thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/jmorrell/backbone-filtered-collection

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to implement a method "getModels" into your collection. Everytime you want to access the collection models you will access this with the getModels method. So you have a centralized point to access the models and this method can filter your results with your custom filtering.